# In Arrow's Impossibility Theorem, what's the difference between a rank vote and a cardinal vote?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

Arrow's impossibility theorem states that in any rank-based voting system involving three or more candidates, at least one of the following criteria will by necessity be violated:

- If every individual prefers Choice A to Choice B, then the group prefers Choice A to Choice B
- If every voter's preferences between Choice A and Choice B remain unchanged, then the group's preferences between Choice A and Choice B remain unchanged
- There is no one "dictator," or individual who can alone sway the group's preferences

However, according to Dr. Kenneth Arrow his theorem does not apply to *cardinal voting systems* as inherently distinct from *rank-based* or *ordinal voting systems*.

What does this mean? What's the difference between a cardinal voting system and a rank-based voting system?

Comment: A cardinal voting system is when the voters give each candidate an independent grade. In a rank-based voting system they supply less information: they only give their order of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, "in Arrow's theorem", there *are no* cardinal votes, since Arrow's theorem only applies to ordinal votes.  The main branches of voting systems are:

- Ranked (ordinal) systems, where voters rank the candidates in order of preference: 1st choice, 2nd choice, 3rd choice, etc.
- Rating (cardinal) systems, where voters rate each candidate independently, so 100% approval, 0% approval, 73% approval, etc.

Rating systems provide more information, since they allow voters to give the same score to multiple candidates, if they feel the same way about each, and to express varying *degrees* of preference.  For instance, if the only three options on the ballot are

- A: Eat strawberry ice cream
- B: Eat chocolate ice cream
- C: Eat rotting garbage

The preference ranking may be A > B > C, but B > C is a much stronger preference than A > B.  Ratings would be more like A: 100%, B: 99%, C: 0%.

If the society's preferences are strictly 1-dimensional, a ranking system carries sufficient information to determine the Condorcet ("beats-all") winner.  If there are two or more dimensions, it does not.

[As I've been told](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14245/10373), Gibbard's theorem applies to *all* conceivable voting systems, proving that they are all subject to strategic voting to some degree.